# Подключение к базе в фоновом режиме

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server

При загрузке приложения заполняю `TableAdapter`. При его заполнении происходит подключение к серверу MS SQL. Если подключение отсутствует, то окно "зависает". Как запустить подключение в фоне.

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                monitorDataSet = ((BidsMonitor.MonitorDataSet)(this.FindResource("monitorDataSet")));
                // Загрузить данные в таблицу BidsView. Можно изменить этот код как требуется.
                bidsTA = new BidsMonitor.MonitorDataSetTableAdapters.BidsViewTableAdapter();
                System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource bidsVS = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("bidsViewViewSource")));

                this.statusIndicator.Fill = Brushes.Yellow;
                this.statusText.Text = "Подключение ...";
                this.statusText.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {
                    try
                    {
                        // В следующей строке происходт подключение к серверу и считываение данных
                        bidsTA.Fill(monitorDataSet.BidsView);

                        bidsVS.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
                        this.statusIndicator.Fill = Brushes.Green;
                        this.statusText.Text = "Подключено";
                        this.updateTimeTextbox.Text = string.Format("Обновлено: {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString());
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        this.statusIndicator.Fill = Brushes.Red;
                        this.statusText.Text = "отсутствует";
                    }
                }), DispatcherPriority.Background);                

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поручим это отдельной задаче `Task.Run()`, а вывод статуса `Dispatcher.Invoke`

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    try
    {
        // В следующей строке происходт подключение к серверу и считываение данных
        bidsTA.Fill(monitorDataSet.BidsView);

        bidsVS.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
        this.statusIndicator.Fill = Brushes.Green;
        this.statusText.Text = "Подключено";
        this.updateTimeTextbox.Text = string.Format("Обновлено: {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString());
        });
    }
    catch
    {
      this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
        this.statusIndicator.Fill = Brushes.Red;
        this.statusText.Text = "отсутствует";
       });
    }
});
```